# How to set suffix names for ipad/hd in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

just started learning cocos2d-x, but found no corresponding cocos2d-x APIs for the following code from cocos2d-iphone:

CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];                // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:"-hd"];        // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd" 
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:"-ipad"];                    // Default on iPad is "ipad" 
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

so how can I customize suffix names in cocos2d-x?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.0.2 version you should use directories for different devices against suffixes in file names. You can see details [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Mechanism_of_loading_resources) and in cocos2dx examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a method in CCFileUtils named setiPadSuffix(and also all the methods you mentioned above) to set the suffix.